# Mac 'screen' command shell script

Tags: macos, shell

I'm working on an i/o project where I have a microcontroller that communicates with my mac through a serial terminal using the screen command in Terminal.app

For example, to open the connection I type "screen /dev/tty.usbserial-number 115200" and then can type commands/data that are sent to the microcontroller

I would like to write a shell script, applescript, c program, or something simple like that that initiates the connection, sends the number "16" and then closes the connection

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to use 'screen'? Can't you just do something like "stty -F 115200 /dev/ttyS0 ; echo '16' >/dev/ttyS0" ? Is there something specific about the setup?

Comment: I have limited experience with Terminal and read on a forum the screen is the best way to implement a serial terminal without third party software. I attempted your suggested method and Terminal returns to a blank line and seems to be waiting for something while there is no response from the microcontroller

Comment: screen works as serial communication software, but you should be able to just send characters to the device. what does stty -f /dev/tty.usbserial-number  return? I assume you need to set it to the correct baud rate first. Is the response from the micro controller something you see elsewhere, or text that you see while using screen? (i.e. text sent back over the serial line)

Comment: I've experimented a little more with it and it seems the only problem is that I can't set the baud rate correctly. I've tried `stty -f tty.usbserial-A100OPI0 115200` and it returns without errors but still doesn't work. After that if I do `stty -f tty.usbserial-A100OPI0` it returns 9600. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: osx usb serial ports seem a little broken.. settings are reset when the file is closed. Anyway, you could use your screen thing to connect to the tty, and then send screen commands to it.. like "screen -X exec echo 16" or some such

Comment: I tried opening the connection and then `screen -X exec echo 16` and it actually prints 16 in the terminal but its not sent to the microcontroller

Comment: oh yeah, you need to tell screen the fdpat to use.. so something like screen -X \!\!\! exec echo 16

Comment: Ah ok. I have decided to switch over to a linux machine because stty and echo > tty actually work on it. I'll see if I can get it to work on my mac eventually. Thanks for your help